# How can I stop my React Native tests bombing out on Flow types in Node Modules?

Tags: javascript, react-native, meteor, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to set up testing on an existing React Native project. When I run a test with Jest, the test bombs out with the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

   ...etc/__app__/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/error-guard.js:14
    type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:16:6)
```

The unexpected identifier is the following:

```
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict
 * @polyfill
 */

let _inGuard = 0;

type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
```

I surmised the issue is related to the separation of the [React and Flow presets](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#separation-of-the-react-and-flow-presets).

The code in node_modules, has Flowtype syntax in it. My Babel configuration applies to my own code, but not to files in node_modules.

My babel.config.js:

```
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', "@babel/preset-flow", "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"],
};
```

My Jest package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|@tableflip/react-native-navbar)",
      "/node_modules/(?!@babel/runtime)",
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|__app__|react-native-button)/)",
      "/node_modules/(?!react-native)/.+"

    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/riteway-jest/src/riteway-jest.js"
    ]
  },
```

How can I stop my tests bombing out on Flow types in Node Modules?

EDIT: Full package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "ReactNativeTest",

  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "start:ios": "react-native run-ios && react-native log-ios",
    "start:android": "react-native run-android && react-native log-android",
    "start:ios:debug": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone X\" & open \"rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081\"",
    "start:android:debug": "react-native run-android & open \"rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081\"",
    "start:debug": "open \"rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081\"",
    "lint": "standard",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "3.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "4.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "3.3.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "ejson": "2.2.0",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.15",
    "lodash.isstring": "4.0.1",
    "markdown-it": "10.0.0",
    "meteor-standalone-random": "1.0.67",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "1.7.3",
    "react-native-config": "0.11.7",
    "react-native-dismiss-keyboard": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.6.0",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-image-picker": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-joi": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "0.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "3.5.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "1.1.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.5.14",
    "react-native-thumbnail-video": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-touch-id": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-uploadcare-image": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "5.0.2",
    "react-native-webview": "7.5.2",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "reduce-reducers": "1.0.4",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-localstorage": "github:tableflip/redux-localstorage#fix-buffer-main-src",
    "redux-localstorage-filter": "0.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "url": "0.11.0",
    "uuid": "3.3.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@babel/runtime)",
      "<rootDir>node_modules/(?!(react-native|__app__|react-native-button)/)",
      "/node_modules/(?!react-native)/.+",
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/riteway-jest.js"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-import-rename": "1.0.1",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.57.0",
    "react-native-config-node": "0.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.12.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.3",
    "riteway-jest": "^2.0.2",
    "standard": "14.3.1"
  },
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "globals": [
      "fetch",
      "FormData",
      "it",
      "expect"
    ]
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

Comment: check if [`babel-jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest) is installed. up to `package.json` looks like it is not.

Comment: babel-jest is installed, I have added dev dependencies

Comment: also try adding it into [`transform` section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest#setup) in `package.json`

Comment: I have also added it to transform section and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: sorry, I've run out of ideas :(

Comment: Did u find the solution for this

Comment: i also have the same issue

Comment: @NabeelK No not yet - what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried @zia?

Comment: this is my error :
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\polyfills\error-guard.js:14
    type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
when i am trying to call npm test my ignore config is :
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
and my test is default react-native test inside App-test.js file
@Sandbagger

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. If anyone has a solution please do let me know.

Comment: Anyone managed to solve this?

Comment: Doesn't work for me with the following ignores (some duplicates):

"node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/)",
      "node_modules/(?!(@|jest-)?react-native|@?react-navigation)",
      "node_modules/(?!(@react-native)/)",
      "node_modules/(?!(@react-navigation)/)"

I have the exact same issue, however

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I needed to add @react-native with '@' into transformIgnorePatterns as shown bellow:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/)"
]
```

Comment: I needed an extra `?` in the regex to allow for modules with/without the `@`. Specifically I used: `node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)`

Comment: This is what I did. Correct me if i did wrong. I added `@react-native|` before `jest` in parentheses. `"node_modules/(?!(@react-native|jest-)?@react-native|react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"`

Answer (score 8):

First, we need to understand what is the root cause.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Basically, these types of errors occurred due to your jest configuration. If you are instructed to transform all the libraries inside the node_modules it will raise these types of erros.
So please go ahead and check for the below statement in your package.json jest configuration.

```
transformIgnorePatterns
```

Above is using to add some transformation ignore patterns and it will have the this default regex pattern => `["/node_modules/", "\\.pnp\\.[^\\\/]+$"]`

Below is from the official jest [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring):

> Sometimes it happens (especially in React Native or TypeScript
> projects) that 3rd party modules are published as untranspiled. Since
> all files inside node_modules are not transformed by default, Jest
> will not understand the code in these modules, resulting in syntax
> errors. To overcome this, you may use transformIgnorePatterns to allow
> transpiling such modules. You'll find a good example of this use case
> in React Native Guide.

So try adding below as instructed by @Pavot in one of the answers will help fix. But if it's a similar issue that occurred by a different library, you can try adding it to the transform ignore list and see whether it works or not.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/)"
]
```

Answer (score 4):

There is issue with **transformIgnorePatterns** in *package.json*.
Instead of adding number of items in this, just follow this pattern to add
modules to blacklist.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!MODULE_NAME_1|MODULE_NAME_2)/"
    ],
```

As from your error, we need to add **react-native** to **transformIgnorePatterns**. Actually, we need to add all those modules in blacklist that throws error because mostly modules are not written completely in JS.

Finally in my case the **jest** in **package.json** is

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native-payfort-sdk|react-native)/"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

This worked for me and hopefully this will help you as well.

Comment: This does not fix the error with React Native 0.63, and the jest "react-native" preset already includes react-native.

Answer (score 4):

Babel might need an according preset. If you are outside Expo, `npm install --save-dev metro-react-native-babel-preset` and insert this to your `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

Comment: Just tested this add unit test for my react-native-web module for native and I was not able to run jest with the same error